# How to specify Decimal as one-off value for Django South migration

Tags: django, django-south

I added a DecimalField to my model

```
dec_field = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)
```

After I tried to create an auto schemamigration file with South, I attempt to specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now, but...

```
? Please enter Python code for your one-off default value.
? The datetime module is available, so you can do e.g. datetime.date.today()
>>> Decimal('15.4')
! Invalid input: name 'Decimal' is not defined
>>> from decimal import *
! Invalid input: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Is it possible for me to specify a Decimal default value (lossless, so float is not ideal), and if so how?

Comment: Did you try just to enter a zero?

Comment: I did not try entering zero. I guess 0 was a bad example. Basically, I want a lossless decimal point representation (so float would be un-ideal)

Comment: The datetime library is not available to you. Why don't you simply add a default value within the field constructor?

Comment: I agree with @Hedde. Adding a default value would be the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking at the code::
https://bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/south/src/81b93bfc927b46227103d094691b5ddcfc25f400/south/creator/actions.py?at=default#cl-190

I tried doing this:

```
    __import__('decimal').Decimal('0.445')
```

and worked

but This is bizarre,
the most correct
would just put a string
it automatically converts

or import Decimal
in that the south migration created

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is indeed bizarre.

The correct answer is that South migrations are, by design, user-editable, and `schemamigration --auto` doesn't always do a perfect work. In this case, I would just enter a value that is easy to find in the file (say, `'0.445'`), then edit the file, add a proper import for `Decimal` and modify the code to use `Decimal('0.445')` instead of the value in the generated migration.